# Why won't this shape fill()?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Why can't I fill() this shape? What's the problem? stroke() works, but not fill().

https://jsfiddle.net/KriegersVan/2fm8oyzv/22/

Thanks for your help!

And now I'm adding some extra text because the question review process is too strict. So it wants me to write some more words in here, which I am now doing.

```
 var visibleCtx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
 var bottomCirclesY = window.innerHeight * 0.50;
 var bottomCirclesX = [
    window.innerWidth / 4,
    window.innerWidth / 2,
    window.innerWidth - (window.innerWidth / 4)
 ];
 var topCircleY = window.innerHeight * 0.20;
 var topCircleLeftX = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (window.innerWidth * 0.17);
 var topCircleRightX = (window.innerWidth / 2) + (window.innerWidth * 0.17);
 var bottomLeftCircleLeftX = bottomCirclesX[0] - (window.innerWidth * 0.08);
 var bottomLeftCircleRightX = bottomCirclesX[0] + (window.innerWidth * 0.08);
 var halfwayBetweenTopAndBottomY = topCircleY + ((bottomCirclesY - topCircleY) / 2);
 var bottomMiddleCircleLeftX = bottomCirclesX[1] - (window.innerWidth * 0.08);
 var bottomMiddleCircleRightX = bottomCirclesX[1] + (window.innerWidth * 0.08);
 var bottomRightCircleLeftX = bottomCirclesX[2] - (window.innerWidth * 0.08);
 var bottomRightCircleRightX = bottomCirclesX[2] + (window.innerWidth * 0.08);

 visibleCtx.beginPath();
 //Draw left tube:
 //Draw left line:
 visibleCtx.moveTo(
    topCircleLeftX,
    topCircleY);
 visibleCtx.lineTo(
    bottomLeftCircleLeftX,
    bottomCirclesY);
 //Draw right line:
 visibleCtx.moveTo(
    topCircleLeftX + (window.innerWidth * 0.08),
    halfwayBetweenTopAndBottomY);
 visibleCtx.lineTo(
    bottomLeftCircleRightX,
    bottomCirclesY);
 //Draw center tube:
 //Draw left line:
 visibleCtx.moveTo(
    bottomMiddleCircleLeftX,
    halfwayBetweenTopAndBottomY);
 visibleCtx.lineTo(
    bottomMiddleCircleLeftX,
    bottomCirclesY);
 //Draw right line:
 visibleCtx.moveTo(
    bottomMiddleCircleRightX,
    halfwayBetweenTopAndBottomY);
 visibleCtx.lineTo(
    bottomMiddleCircleRightX,
    bottomCirclesY);
 //Draw right tube:
 //Draw left line:
 visibleCtx.moveTo(
    topCircleRightX - (window.innerWidth * 0.08),
    halfwayBetweenTopAndBottomY);
 visibleCtx.lineTo(
    bottomRightCircleLeftX,
    bottomCirclesY);
 //Draw right line:
 visibleCtx.moveTo(
    topCircleRightX,
    topCircleY);
 visibleCtx.lineTo(
    bottomRightCircleRightX,
    bottomCirclesY);
 //Connect the lines:
 //Draw left connector:
 visibleCtx.moveTo(
    topCircleLeftX + (window.innerWidth * 0.08),
    halfwayBetweenTopAndBottomY);
 visibleCtx.lineTo(
    bottomMiddleCircleLeftX,
    halfwayBetweenTopAndBottomY);
 //Draw right connector:
 visibleCtx.moveTo(
    topCircleRightX - (window.innerWidth * 0.08),
    halfwayBetweenTopAndBottomY);
 visibleCtx.lineTo(
    bottomMiddleCircleRightX,
    halfwayBetweenTopAndBottomY);
 //Connect the top lines:
 visibleCtx.moveTo(
    topCircleLeftX,
    topCircleY);
 visibleCtx.lineTo(
    topCircleRightX,
    topCircleY);
 //Connect the bottom lines
 //Draw the left tube line:
 visibleCtx.moveTo(
    bottomLeftCircleLeftX,
    bottomCirclesY);
 visibleCtx.lineTo(
    bottomLeftCircleRightX,
    bottomCirclesY);
 //Draw the center tube line:
 visibleCtx.moveTo(
    bottomMiddleCircleLeftX,
    bottomCirclesY);
 visibleCtx.lineTo(
    bottomMiddleCircleRightX,
    bottomCirclesY);
 //Draw the right tube line:
 visibleCtx.moveTo(
    bottomRightCircleLeftX,
    bottomCirclesY);
 visibleCtx.lineTo(
    bottomRightCircleRightX,
    bottomCirclesY);

 visibleCtx.fillStyle = "#18dbd8";
 visibleCtx.lineJoin = "round";
 visibleCtx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
 visibleCtx.fill();
 visibleCtx.stroke();
 visibleCtx.closePath();
```

Comment: I just tried your fiddle and the fill() didnt fill. My best guess is that in the way that you draw your path, your `moveto`s could be throwing it off. Instead try drawing the path (after your first `moveto`) in such a way that the beginning coord is the same as the ending coord, and without using `moveto`s to jump around.

Comment: This is because the moveTo's are creating a bunch of disconnected lines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave any gaps it doesn't seem to work, I think you need to not "moveTo" on your shapes.

with this at the start of both

```
visibleCtx.beginPath();
```

Try this small snippet

```
        visibleCtx.moveTo(
            topCircleLeftX,
            topCircleY
        );
        visibleCtx.lineTo(
            bottomLeftCircleLeftX,
            bottomCirclesY
        );
        //Draw right line:
        visibleCtx.moveTo(
            topCircleLeftX+(window.innerWidth*0.08),
            halfwayBetweenTopAndBottomY
        );
        visibleCtx.lineTo(
            bottomLeftCircleRightX,
            bottomCirclesY
        );
```

vs

```
        visibleCtx.moveTo(
            topCircleLeftX,
            topCircleY
        );
        visibleCtx.lineTo(
            bottomLeftCircleLeftX,
            bottomCirclesY
        );
        //Draw right line:
        visibleCtx.lineTo(
            topCircleLeftX+(window.innerWidth*0.08),
            halfwayBetweenTopAndBottomY
        );
        visibleCtx.lineTo(
            bottomLeftCircleRightX,
            bottomCirclesY
        );
```

put this at the end of both

```
visibleCtx.fillStyle = "#18dbd8";
visibleCtx.lineJoin = "round";
visibleCtx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
visibleCtx.fill();
visibleCtx.stroke();
visibleCtx.closePath();
```

to see the difference.  One leaves gaps, the other does not.  I think this is because every `moveTo` is a separate shape to `fill()`.